# How to avoid using JavaScript eval() in user-defined function

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I'm trying to make a generic table-top RPG helper web app.  It has to be generic because Wizards of the Coast is very protective of their copyrights.  So, in order to avoid cease-and-desists, the system has to be capable of loading arbitrary rules.  That said, my buddies and I (along with most any other user) will be using it for D&D.

In D&D, modifiers are based on a character's stats.  To get a modifier, you take the stat, subtract 10, divide by 2, and round down.

```
function getModifier(statValue) {
    return Math.floor((statValue - 10) / 2);
}
```

My app will be capable to loading a game's rules from a .json file.  I want to be able to make this modifier function user-definable.  The easiest way would be to just `eval()` whatever they provide in the .json file, but obviously that's a terrible idea due to security issues.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a simple way to get around this in a secure manner.  Obviously I could write my own parser, but that's more complicated than I'd like/am currently capable of.

Ideas?

Comment: use `JSON.parse`. JSON does not define functions.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will take the json file and return a javascript object, right?  The getModifier value will then be a string, and I'll need to parse that string in order to get a function.  How do I do that in a secure way, since users can input an arbitrary string for this value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what a modifier is. Can you give a few examples of user-defined modifiers?

Comment: Are you running JavaScript in the browser, or are you using node.js or something similar instead?

Comment: there isn't a way - could you program in some options for the user?

Comment: A modifier is just a game mechanic in D&D.  It's used for determining now strong or intelligent or powerful you are, based on your stats.

Comment: Is the modifier function always a single mathematical expression? In that case you could just write your own parser or use an already existing one.

Comment: You need to define a set of meta-rules that allow you to define rules for a particular system. If all such meta-rules are mathematical, maybe you can get away with a mathematical-expression parser.

Comment: @Frxstrem This'll be running in the browser, but it will be running on machines other than the person who inputted the file.

Comment: @SpiderPig They should all be simple mathematical expressions.  The trick would be the `floor()` function.  Do you know of a parser that includes that? (Awesome name, btw.)

Comment: So a modifier is a function that takes a set of stats and returns a single number? Do I have that right? How do you propose to represent stats? As a hash of arbitrary key/value pairs, perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Yes, it's a function on a single number.  Stats are string-int pairs.

Comment: For example, `var modifier = function (stats) { return stats.armor * 2 - stats.grue + Math.floor(stats.fish / 3); }`? Like that?

Comment: I did a quick google search and found two options - http://mathjs.org and http://jsep.from.so

Comment: It appears that SpiderPig has found what you need.

Comment: btw. writing your own parser is not that difficult. You may be able to write one that's sufficient for your purpose in less than 100 lines of code.

Comment: It looks like math.js (which I'm already using, as it turns out) will be sufficient.  Want to write up an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google search and found two options - http://mathjs.org and http://jsep.from.so

btw. writing your own parser is not that difficult. You may be able to write one that's sufficient for your purpose in less than 100 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

First, bear in mind that this is all on the client-side. So long as you trust the JSON (it came from your server or it is controlled alongside the application itself), then you can use it. That doesn't completely rule out some trojan inserting malicious rules, but I don't think botnets have learned to play D&D yet.

To *literally* avoid eval and provide some modicum of security, you can use [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). It takes a list of argument names followed by the function body, allowing you a large amount of control over how the function is defined and where it can be referenced from. You only need to store the body in the JSON file, allowing you to largely control the parameters and make it difficult to assign to the global scope, minimizing your attack surface (such as it is) quite a lot.

If you want to *have fun* with this and now your rules will largely be mathematical, you may consider using a tool like [pegjs](http://pegjs.org/) to generate a parser for your rules. Calculators are one of the classic introductions to parsers and compilers, so this could be an opportunity to play with some fun tech. The rules and parsers built by pegjs are very easy to use in a JS project (I have [an example using PegJS and ES6 via Babel](https://github.com/ssube/babel-peg)).

Comment: Do functions defined with `new Function` have access to objects like XHRs and global assignments like `$` or `jQuery`, or only the passed arguments?

Comment: They can access those via `window.$`, but you can try to obfuscate those somewhat (add code to the head of the function that defines them all to null, for example). Still, being client-side, security will never be absolute.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to use [sandboxed iframes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) (current supported by [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox)

You run user code on a separate page, with limited priviliges, in such a way that the code does not interfere with the rest of the application. You can communicate with the sandboxed page using [`postMessage()`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) and `window.onmessage`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options as I see it. One, if you 100% want to define the function in .json, you will need to parse. JSON does not allow functions, so you need to store the function as a string and eval it.

The better way would be to also provide a config.js ability. Perhaps the `.json` would have a `"configUrl":` property, and then expose well known apis, eg `RPGHelper.setModifer(someFunction)` that you can call from inside the config.js file. The user is then free to define whatever arbitrary logic there.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is figuring out how to allow function-like definitions while eliminating or sandboxing any bad stuff that could possibly happen in a function defined by another user.